# How to protect a block of code from global variable leak in PHP?

Tags: php

Very often, when I have a small config file such as a Doctrine [cli-config.php](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html#configuration) file, I need to use a few temporary variables that I don't want to leak as global variables when this file is included somewhere else.

For example, in the following config file, `$container` and `$em` leak in the context of the code that includes it:

```php
$container = Bootstrap::createDependencyInjectionContainer();
$em = $container->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

return new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
    'db' => new Helper\ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()),
    'em' => new Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em)
));
```

In Javascript, I could isolate a block of code by using the following construct:

```js
(function() {

})();
```

But in PHP, even though [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) do exist, the construct above does not work:

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in ...

So the only way I can see to protect my temporary variables from being global is to wrap the code in a named function:

```php
function create_my_config() {
    // wrap the cli-config.php code above
}

return create_my_config();
```

But this now leaks a global function name. Sure, I could namespace it, but I'm not sure this is much better.

**Is there a way to isolate a block of code and all its variables without creating a named function?**

Comment: If I am not wrong was the bracket of array suppose to close at getConnection()")". Because I can see addtional ")" in the code

Comment: @grvpanchal Nope, the code is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP  does not support self calling anonymous function, but you can still call it with [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/call_user_func)

index.php:

```
<?php
$config = require 'config.php';
```

config.php:

```
<?php
return call_user_func(function(){
    return ["host" => "localhost", "user" => "root", "password" => ""];
});
```